# How to restrict the login google api with specific domain name only?

Tags: python, django, google-api, google-oauth, django-socialauth

I'm creating a web application which I'm using Google API for authentication. Also, the library that I've applied was **social-auth-app-django**. Then, my goal is to allow only specific domain name like **user@example.com** with a domain of **example.com**.

Upon reading its documentation this line of code should be added to ***settings.py*** **SOCIAL_AUTH__WHITELISTED_DOMAINS = ['foo.com', 'bar.com']** however, it is not working to me.

**settings.py** configuration

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_WHITELISTED_DOMAINS = ['example.com.hk']
```

How can I restrict the google api to only allow the specified whitelisted domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add and specify the authorize domains to your google API credentials.

Comment: Okay! Got it Thankss!

Comment: Hey Benj, how to add and specify the authorize domains to your google API credentials?